# Caching or saving an image from web Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I currently have an app that loads an image from the web like this

```
[self.userImage setImageWithURL:IMAGEURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"userPhoto.png"]];
```

and it works perfectly. I'm still wondering if I can somehow save or cache the image so it shows up quicker when the user opens the app again.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

After importing SDWebImage to my class and upon compiling I get this error

```
Ld "DerivedData/Social App/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Social App.app/Social App" normal i386
    cd "/Users/iamgretara/Documents/YouTube app "
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 5.0
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk "-L/Users/iamgretara/Documents/YouTube app /DerivedData/Social App/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator" "-L/Users/iamgretara/Documents/YouTube app /GDATA" "-F/Users/iamgretara/Documents/YouTube app /DerivedData/Social App/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator" -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist "/Users/iamgretara/Documents/YouTube app /DerivedData/Social App/Build/Intermediates/Social App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Social App.build/Objects-normal/i386/Social App.LinkFileList" -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=5.0 -framework ImageIO -framework MediaPlayer -framework CoreText -framework AVFoundation -framework SystemConfiguration -framework Security -framework QuartzCore -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o "/Users/iamgretara/Documents/YouTube app /DerivedData/Social App/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Social App.app/Social App"

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MKAnnotationView", referenced from:
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_MKAnnotationView_$_WebCache in MKAnnotationView+WebCache.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[Image of error](http://gyazo.com/72ec8ef60aaf9ba333cf3e21d5706ade.png)

Comment: Is this a [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) method (which already does disk cacheing)? [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) method? It would help to know which library's `UIImageView` category you're using.

Comment: It's an AFNetworking method.

Comment: What does this error mean ? Got it after compiling SDWebImage http://gyazo.com/72ec8ef60aaf9ba333cf3e21d5706ade.png

Comment: @IamGretar Your compilation error means that you need to add MapKit to your project's frameworks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can save the file to disk yourself and check if it exists before you try to load it (all based on URL matching). There are also libraries that will do this kind of stuff for you like `SDWebImage` / `HJCache`.

Comment: Alright, I tried to use it but I got this error upon compiling http://gyazo.com/72ec8ef60aaf9ba333cf3e21d5706ade.png

Comment: How did you do the installation? Your project probably doesn't have MapKit so you have included too many files.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [AsyncImageView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView). It has inbuilt caching support.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

you can try with [EGOImageLoading](https://github.com/enormego/EGOImageLoading)
 for image caching support.